# How can I get the categorized reputation of a user into different tags?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump, data

I am trying to get the score of different users into different tags. I am using the platform https://data.stackexchange.com/ to get that information. For example, writing the query:

```
Select Id, Reputation from Users where Id in (4333347,213615)
```

gives me the following result:

```
Id       Reputation
213615   3344
4333347  3587
```

However, I want the reputation into different tags like: `213615 => Java : 1500, Python 200`. Is there any way I can achieve that?

It is okay if the total score is more than the total reputation. The query aims at seeing the top technologies/expertise of an user.

Comment: As in - for each user you want to know what contribution each tag had toward their reputation? What if there are multiple tags which go together often (e.g. C# and .NET) - the total could be more than the reputation of the user.

Comment: It's fine if the total goes more than the reputation. I am interested to see the top technologies by a user through this query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following [pivot query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1126438) does that for you.

Notice that I didn't do a full/correct reputation calc, just the bits based on voting and neglecting any reputation cap, offered bounties, accepted question. I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

For performance reasons the userid's are scattered around on 3 places. Sorry for that but I didn't fancy making that dynamic.

```
;with post_rep as
(
  select owneruserid
       , tagname
       , sum(
         case posttypeid 
         when 1 then --Q
           case votetypeid
           when 2 then 5
           when 3 then -2
           else 0
           end
         when 2 then --A
           case votetypeid
           when 1 then 15
           when 2 then 10
           when 3 then -2
           when 9 then bountyamount
           else 0
           end
         else
          0
         end
         ) reputation
  from posts p
  inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
  inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
  inner join votes v on v.postid = p.id
  where v.votetypeid in (1,2,3,9)
  and owneruserid in (4333347 ,213615)
  group by owneruserid
       , tagname
)
-- Select Id, Reputation from Users where Id in (4333347,213615)

select tagname, [4333347] ,[213615]
from (
   select *
   from post_rep
) as pvt
PIVOT
(
sum(reputation) for owneruserid in ([4333347] ,[213615])
) data
order by [4333347] + [213615] desc
```

When run today this is what the result looks like:

[image: tags for two users and their rep]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday. Give a big shout-out to [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) for the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) she wrote. Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: I didn’t realize Monica was a SQL expert. She continues to surprise me with her talents.