# How can I format plain code as text without any highlighting?

Tags: discussion, markdown, markdown-rendering

I made several attempts in my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61681446/how-to-match-my-specific-hashtag-pattern) to format a block of text so that it has no highlighting.

I tried to prefix with space, to wrap in ```` ```text ```` or `~~~text` but it always ends as

```
#hashtag some text #hash; #123
 and # not because markdown
# that not
#33 that is not
either but #3isok
 or #isok3
astring#andthatshouldnotmatch
 #hashtagalone
 \n#hashatthebeginning
hello #hashattheend\n
#has_htag
#ano-the-rone
```

`either`, `but`, `astring`, etc. are highlighted.

Comment: This is also covered in [the Markdown Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: The canonical (most detailed) is *[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)* (cross-site)

Answer (score 5):

`~~~none` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not realize that you edited my question and could not see the highlighting anymore :). One thing that is a bit strange is that on Meta the same code (formatted with ` ~~~text `) is not highlighted.

Comment: There are no language tags on Meta that can be used to infer the higlighting language.

Comment: @WoJ  I think the difference between main and meta is that on main an unrecognized lang-hint is converted to lang-default whereas on meta if it converted to lang-none.

Comment: @Cerbrus there certainly are: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390486/578411

Comment: Okay, _"There are no language tags on this Meta question <...>"_ :D